Altium Polygon Custom Queries keep disappearing
I've had this problem with Altium custom queries for as long as I can remember, and I'm tired of dealing with it. So I wanted to post my question about this here to see if I can get some input.
I've been having this issue with my custom query for my polygon pour disappearing when I close the application. Of course when making the query, I save the changes to the rule, the PCB file, and the project file. I can even see the changes on my board as I add the custom query. But today when I went to return to my PCB design, the custom queries I have set have just decided to disappear, and I need to add them all over again. I don't understand why this is happening, and it's been happening for a while, knowingly on Altium V22 and V24. I've been using logic OR for my custom query so I can affect multiple Polygons under the same rule, so I don't know if that has anything to do with my issue. Has anyone experienced this issue, or have any advice to keep this from happening?
Current query. There should be more here


Okay, so I figured it out, and I'm adding this answer in case anyone come across this issue in the future.
When using Query's in Alitum, you are able to use Logic notation, such as And, Or, Not. For my Query's I was using the "||" as a logic or like in  C programming. This is not okay. You have to use the verbiage Or and not the logic symbol.

This doesn't seem to be it -- both styles of operator are documented and current: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/query-language#filter-toolbar I don't recall ever seeing queries change/reset on OK-ing the dialog; if the behavior is consistent on e.g. a new document and after restarting AD, it may be worth bug reporting it. In the mean time, have you considered polygon classes?
